# Calculator Input - TextField

Tags: ios, nsstring, textfield

I would like to know how to implement a single line of calculation with parenthesis in textfield.

I would like to get textstring input and parse it accordingly to get proper values and send it the following code or any other suggested method

```
#import "calculate.h"

@implementation calculate


+(double)arithmetic:(double)firstNumber enterCharacter:(int)characterType enterSecond:(double)secondNumber
{
    double result;

    switch (characterType)
    {
        case 0:
            result= firstNumber+secondNumber;
            break;
        case 1:
            result= firstNumber-secondNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result= firstNumber/secondNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result= firstNumber*secondNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result= pow(firstNumber,secondNumber);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
    return result;


}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: In order to do that, you're going to have to figure out the old syaing you learned in school, Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally. You need to determine if there are parentheses; if so, then figure out those calculations first. Then move to multiply/divide/etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already an object in the SDK that will handle much of this for you called [NSExpression](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/). Be sure to check out the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) as well.